# Names of two manifold-like structures

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm looking for the canonical names of (and optionally a reference for) the following structures:

1. The result of cutting out, from a differentiable manifold homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, an "open ball", i.e. an open, bounded region whose boundary is a closed, differentiable $n-1$ dimensional hypersurface
2. The same as 1., but let the closed hypersurface be non-differentiable somewhere.

Is the first perhaps a "solid $n$-torus"? And thus the second a "solid $n$-torus 'with corners' "?

Many thanks for any help/pointers!

Comment: "inside of a differentiable closed curve with winding number 1" makes no sense at all.

Comment: Sorry, right --- I initially wrote out the question for $n=2$, but then last minute switched to the more general case, forgetting to appropriately change the rest. I hope it's fixed now?

Comment: Even for $n=3$, the [solid torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_torus) terminology applies only in one very special situation, namely certain embeddings $S^1 \times S^1 \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^3$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4207457/embedded-surface-in-mathbb-r3 for a general discussion when $n=3$. Anyway, your question asks for a canonical name, and like many such questions the only possible response is that there is no canonical name.

Comment: I see -- thank you! I take it there's also not a canonical name for a structure that's just like a differentiable manifold-with-boundary except that its boundary is somewhere not differentiable?

Comment: Make sure you do not use the "open ball" terminology unless the subset is really diffeomorphic or homeomorphic to the open ball.

Comment: Gotcha -- will make sure, thanks!